# Solving ODE by finite differences and Newton's method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, finite-differences

Given this boundary value problem

$y'' = (x^2(y')^2 - 9y^2 + 4x^6)/x^5, \quad 1 \leq x \leq 2, \qquad (1)\\
y(1) = 0, \; y(2) = \ln 256$

I have to solve the problem using finite differences, for 21 points (difference = 0.05), and use Newton's method to solve the nonlinear system generated by the problem discretization.

Using the $y'$ and $y''$ substitutions by finite differences in the equation 1, I've got that

$
 - (x_j^2/4)y_{j+1}^2 + (9 h^2)y_j^2 - (x_j^2/4) y_{j-1}^2 
 + (x_j^5)y_{j+1} + (x_j^2/2) y_{j+1} y_{j-1} +  (x_j^5)y_{j-1}
 - (2x_j^5)y_j - 4x_j^6h^2 = 0
$

I'd know how to solve if it was linear, but I still don't know how to solve this by Newton's method.

Comment: Entering *newton method system of nonlinear equations* into your favorite search engine should help.

Comment: Actually, it helped me a lot. The way I did by searching what you said was calling $y_{j}$, $y_{j-1}$, $y_{j+1}$ and $x_{j}$ by $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$, $x_{3}$ e $k$, respectively:

$F(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (- (k^2/4) x_3^2 + (9 h^2) x_1^2 - (k^2/4) x_2^2 + (k^5) x_3 + (k^2/2) x_3 x_2 +  (k^5) x_2 - (k^5) x_1 - 4 k^6 h^2 = 0$

Then, I did Newton's method to find $x_1$ ($y_j$).
The initial guess is that $y_j$, $y_{j+1}$ and $y_{j-1}$ are equal to $y_{j-1}$ (the last calculated, starting with $y(1) = 0$.
Still, the values converge from y(2).